# SQL CTE vs Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am running into a bit of a stumper here.  My main goal is to be able to use this in C# and Entity Framework and our directive from on high is to stay away from stored procedures.

I have 2 tables: a xref and a (Celko) tree table.

```
/**
 ** Table [dbo].[EntityXref]
 **/
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'EntityXref' AND type = N'U')
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[EntityXref]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.[EntityXref]
( Id                BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
, EntityId          INT NOT NULL
, EntityTypeId      INT NOT NULL
, ChildEntityId     INT NOT NULL
, ChildEntityTypeId INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityXref] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_EntityXref] UNIQUE CLUSTERED (EntityId, EntityTypeId, ChildEntityId, ChildEntityTypeId)
)


/**
 ** Table [dbo].[EntityTree]
 **/
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = N'EntityTree' AND type = N'U')
    DROP TABLE dbo.EntityTree
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.EntityTree
( Id            BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
, SystemId      INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 
, EntityId      INT NOT NULL -- could be an AgencyId, UserId, ClientId, VendorId, etc
, EntityTypeId  INT NOT NULL -- Defines the entity type
, isActive      BIT NOT NULL
, lft           BIGINT NOT NULL 
, rgt           BIGINT NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityTree] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_Entity]     UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (EntityId, EntityTypeId)
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_Left]       UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([lft])
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_LeftRight]  UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([lft], [rgt])
)
GO
```

The basic tree data looks like:

> Customer -> Agencies -> Users -> Clients

We also have Users who manage multiple agencies, hence the xref (poor name) table.  I am testing with a single user that has overview of 98% of the agencies and I need all of the clients. So, my conundrum:

NOTE:

- EntityTypeId = 7 --> User account used for report generation
- EntityTypeId = 4 --> Client account

This takes 4 seconds to run but cannot be expressed as a view:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
( childentityid INT
, childentitytypeid INT
)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT et.RootEntityId, et.RootEntityTypeId
  FROM dbo.EntityXref et
 WHERE et.EntityId = 17088 AND et.EntityTypeId = 7    

SELECT * 
  FROM @t a
 INNER JOIN dbo.GetMyCaseLoad b ON a.RootEntityId = b.ParentEntityId AND a.RootEntityTypeId = b.ParentEntityTypeId
GO
```

This takes 36-40 seconds to run (several different permutations on this join!)

```
WITH xrefParent (parentEntityId, parentEntityTypeId)    --, rootEntityId, rootEntityTypeId)
  AS (SELECT ChildEntityId, ChildEntityTypeId /*, EntityId, EntityTypeId */ FROM dbo.EntityXref WHERE EntityId = 17088 AND EntityTypeId = 7) 
SELECT *
  FROM GetMyCaseLoad cl
 INNER JOIN xrefParent p ON cl.ParentEntityId = p.parentEntityId AND cl.ParentEntityTypeId = p.parentEntityTypeId
-- WHERE p.rootEntityId = 17088 AND p.rootEntityTypeId = 7
GO
```

Any ideas on how to get the **benefits** of the temp table into a view for consumption by Entity Framework?

---

Added definitions:

```
CREATE VIEW GetMyCaseLoad AS
SELECT Parent.Id            [ParentRecordId]
     , Parent.EntityId      [ParentEntityId]
     , Parent.EntityTypeId  [ParentEntityTypeId]
     , Child.SystemId       [ChildSystemId]
     , Child.Id             [ChildRecordId]
     , Child.EntityId       [ChildEntityId]
     , Child.EntityTypeId   [ChildEntityTypeId]
     , Child.isActive       [ChildIsActive]
     , Child.lft            [ChildLeft]
     , Child.rgt            [ChildRight]
  FROM dbo.EntityTree Parent
     , dbo.EntityTree Child
 WHERE Child.lft > Parent.lft
   AND Child.rgt < Parent.rgt
   AND Child.EntityTypeId = 4
GO


CREATE VIEW GetMyFullCaseLoad AS
SELECT x.Id             [XrefRecordId]
     , x.EntityId       [XrefParentEntityId]
     , x.EntityTypeId   [XrefParentEntityTypeId]
     , c.ParentRecordId
     , c.ParentEntityId
     , c.ParentEntityTypeId
     , c.ChildRecordId
     , c.ChildEntityId
     , c.ChildEntityTypeId
     , c.ChildIsActive
     , c.ChildLeft
     , c.ChildRight
     , x.CanRead
     , x.CanWrite 
  FROM EntityXref x
 INNER JOIN dbo.GetMyCaseLoad c ON x.ChildEntityId = c.ParentEntityId AND x.ChildEntityTypeId = c.ParentEntityTypeId
GO
```

The 2nd view is what we are trying to speed up.

SIDE NOTE:  The current system takes about 2-3 minutes to bring back records.  The 2nd view or CTE does it in 40 seconds based on a new data structure (adjacency tree vs set tree).  With the temp table 4 seconds.

Comment: I wonder if you could create a sample demo in sqlFiddle so we can have something to work. You maybe want create a simpler example just to show the key issue. Also performace question should include `EXPLAIN PLAN`

Comment: What is `GetMyCaseLoad`? Is that a view or a table?

Comment: I don't quite see what the CTE is doing for you, other than making the query harder to read.  I doubt it confuses SQL Server, but it possibly will confuse *you* or your colleagues at some point in the future.

Comment: Why is there a moratorium on stored procedures? That seems like a strange and arbitrary decision made by somebody who doesn't understand sql server very well.

Comment: I'm with @JohnBollinger.. i dont see why you can't just inner join to `EntityXref` and add the filters to your main `WHERE`

Comment: More details added to question.  @juan - You mean a screen scrape (image) of explain plan?

Comment: If the benefits of a temp table are just improved performance then I suggest you tune the performance first (indexes etc.), unless indexes are also frowned upon :p

Comment: Where is the execution plan for the query? How can we possibly diagnose the problem without this?

Comment: To add to what Sean Lange is saying: let those from on high explain why they are so against Stored Procedures... It doesn't make much sense. In any case without an execution plan for your query, there isn't much we can do to help other than give general answers (like the one I gave). In all likelihood the `VIEW` (or the query on the `VIEW`) is unable to benefit from INDEXES in the underlying tables (if they have any).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with CTE's is that they are not materialized, they do not have dedicated statistics (they rely on statistics of the underlying objects), they don't have indexes (although in some cases they can use indexes on referenced tables).

The upsides of temporary tables is that they are inherently materialized (in tempdb), they can have indexes (if you define them) and most definitely have dedicated statistics.

In a lot of cases that means that using temporary tables instead of CTEs can produce better execution plans. Using a CTE will almost never speed up things, while a temporary table in a lot of cases will.

I will defer to a higher authority than me and leave you with his quote:

> A CTE should never be used for performance. You will almost never speed things up by using a CTE because it's just a disposable view. You can do some neat things with them but speeding up a query isn't really one of them.

This quote is from the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/65699) to the question *"What's the difference between a CTE and a Temp Table?"*

PS: I see that you are using a `TABLE` variable in your first query. This is not the same as a temporary table. A temporary table will almost always beat a `TABLE` variable in terms of performance. For a good essay on the difference between `TABLE` variables and temporary tables, read this [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/65699) on the question *"What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?"*.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on dbo.EntityXref(EntityId, EntityTypeId)?

I'm guessing this because that's really the only difference that the temp table will make, that it will only table scan once when inserting into the temp table if you don't have an index. In the other permutations, it might become a looped table scan.

The only thing worse than a table scan is a looped table scan.